# Sublimit $\mathbb{N}$ of sequence.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> **Problem**:
>   Is there sequence that sublimit are $\mathbb{N}$? If it's eqsitist prove this.

I try to solve this problem by guessing what type of sequence need to be. 
For example:
$a_n=(-1)^n$ has two sublimit $\{1,-1\}$.

$a_n=n
\times\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$ has 0 sublimit because $\lim _{x\to \infty}{n\times\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})}=\infty$. 
But I don't know how to solve this so please give me a hint.

Comment: Do you want "sublimit" instead of "limit point"? Quite different.

Comment: OK. Now the answer by @sigmabe is fine, before it was wrong.

Comment: Also for the "limit point" case, you can do it in a similar way. Add $1/m$ when you have restarted for $m$ times.

Comment: @Jonas What's the difference? Or what is sublimit anyway? Does an explaination fit in a comment or does it merit an own question?

Comment: For "limit point" you require that any neighborhood has some point other than the limit point. For "sublimit" (or perhaps there is a better name) you only require that some subsequence converges to the sublimit.

Answer (score 1):

There is such a sequence. For example make it by counting. Fix a natural $n$, first count to $n$, then start again and count to $n+1$, then to $n+2$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Such a sequence exists and this is possible due to the (not so intuitive perhaps) fact, that $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N$ have the same cardinality (surprise!). But since they have the same cardinality, there is a bijection (actually many), $b:\mathbb N \times \mathbb N\to \mathbb N$. Now, for any $m \in \mathbb N$ the sequence that is defined as $$a_{m,n}:=m$$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$ is a sequence with limit points all $m \in \mathbb N$ and so has the desired property but is a sequence in $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$. So, use this bijection and define the sequence $x:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ as $$x_{b(m,n)}=m$$ which is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_m$ be the $m$th prime.For $n\in N,$ if $n=(p_m)^k$ for some $m,k\in N,$ let $x_n=m+1.$ If $n$ is not a power of a prime, let $x_n=1.$